# React-select: Default values only update if they are set statically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am trying to display the list of interests based on this object received from backend:

```
 profile : {
  interest: ["interest1", "interest2"],
};
```

This is how I implemented it:

```
import Creatable from "react-select/creatable";

class EditProfileInSettings extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      previously_selected_interests: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { interest } = nextProps.profile;
    if (!!interest) {
      const previously_selected_interests = interest.map((interest) => ({
        _id: interest._id,
        value: interest.name,
        label: interest.name,
        color: "#FF8B00",
      }));
      this.setState({
        previously_selected_interests,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    let { previously_selected_interests } = this.state;
    return (
      <Creatable
        cacheOptions
        isMulti
        defaultValue={previously_selected_interests}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that even though inside render the `previously_selected_interests` passed to `defaultValue` are logged correctly:

> ~ file: EditProfileInSettings.js ~ line 64 ~ EditProfileInSettings
> ~ render ~ previously_selected_interests []

> ~ file:
> EditProfileInSettings.js ~ line 64 ~ EditProfileInSettings ~ render ~
> previously_selected_interests  (2) [{…}, {…}] 0: {_id:
> "609cd8253acf49906990d712", value: "mythology", label: "mythology",
> color: "#FF8B00"} 1: {_id: "609cd8253acf49906990d790", value:
> "listening to music", label: "listening to music", color: "#FF8B00"}
> length: 2
> **proto**: Array(0)

They do not get displayed:
[image]

But, when I set the exact same values statically inside render:

```
  render() {
    let { previously_selected_interests } = this.state;
    previously_selected_interests = [
      {
        _id: "609cd8253acf49906990d712",
        value: "interest1",
        label: "interest1",
        color: "#FF8B00",
      },
      {
        _id: "609cd8253acf49906990d790",
        value: "interest2",
        label: "interest2",
        color: "#FF8B00",
      },
    ];
    return (
      <Creatable
        cacheOptions
        isMulti
        defaultValue={previously_selected_interests}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

They do get displayed:
[image]
Which makes absolutely no sense, since they are the exact same array of the exact same objects.
So for some reason `Creatable` component doesn't update `defaultValue`.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is `Creatable`?

Comment: Also, why are you using `componentWillReceiveProps`?  That's deprecated.  Have you tried this with `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: @SethLutske I just added Creatable in the code. It's the search box from react-select that allows you to create an option if it doesn't exist already in the result of searched options.

Comment: @SethLutske Does it make sense to you that previously_selected_interests get logged correctly inside render but they don't get rendered. And they do if I set them statically there?

Comment: If within render, the values you're looking for are logging correctly, then it indeed does not make sense.  My best suggestion is to recreate your bug in a codesandbox and share the link here so we can truly see the problem in action - thats the best way for us to help debug.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the issue on react-select Github Repo and I got my answer:
the `defaultValue` prop is is designed for "uncontrolled" behaviour of components. Using it will only change the value for the initial render of the component. You should Instead use the `value` prop (in combination with the `onChange` prop to handle changes):

```
        <Creatable
          cacheOptions
          options={interests_options}
          isMulti
          value={previously_selected_interests_to_display}
          onInputChange={this.handleInterestsInputChange}
          onChange={this.onSelectedInterest}
        />
```